# Insert jQuery generated Label Text Into Database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I use to script below to display a label text.

```
$('#<%=Label3.ClientID%>').html("<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + sender.newFileName3);
```

I also want to insert the generated text into the database, but it doesn't work. The default text value of the label is inserted into the database and not the new value from the jquery that appears on the browser.

Comment: What about the code where you're actually trying to store the value in your database? Also are you aware of that you can't just access your front-end element values from the c# code?

Comment: *but it doesn't work.* => http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/

Comment: You have to post the code that is attempting to save the "new" value in the database, specifically the client-side code that is calling to the server to pass the "new" value to the server. Is your server code ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the values of ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) and sender.newFileName3 are generated on the server side.
If this is ASP webforms, you need to write these values into the database in the code behind.
If this is MVC, in the views controller.
Do it before the page is sent to the client.